# Zlib: What is the difference between inflating, encoding, and compressing a string?

Tags: php, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which compression method to use in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621976/which-compression-method-to-use-in-php)

It seems that PHP has many [functions for making smaller strings out of strings](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zlib.php). These functions are called inflate/deflate, encode/decode, and compress/uncompress. Some of them seem compatible with each other, as all are base on the `zlib` library. What is the differences between them, and when to use each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the function documentation linked to from the page in your link:

- [gzdeflate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php) - use the 'clean' [DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm with the deflate data format.
- [gzcompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) - use the [ZLIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZLIB) data format that add extra header and trailer data on the DEFLATE algorithm. As to [RFC 1950](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html) it "can be easily extended to use
  other compression methods".
- [gzencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) - use the [gzip application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) data format that includes some more header data over the ZLIB format.