# change zlib.decompress from python to php

Tags: php, python

I want convert a python code to php.

my problem is this line (python):

```
zlib.decompress( $gzipped, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS );
```

I don't know zlib.MAX_WBITS in php

my code (in php)  :

```
$response = gzuncompress( $gzipped, ??? );
```

Comment: You can leave it blank, it's optional parameter

Comment: this parameter is max length of decoding. here talks about it. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021895/zlib-inflate-give-data-error-in-php  .seems it is important

Answer (score 1):

**Answer edited after feedback**

It's a bit of a hassle, but you can do it with PHP [compression filters](http://www.php.net//manual/en/filters.compression.php).

```
$params = array('window' => 31);
$fp = fopen('your_data', 'rb');
stream_filter_append($fp, 'zlib.inflate', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $params);
print fread($fp, 1024);
```

The only problem is that you need to source the compressed data from a stream... I'm no PHP guy so I will leave that to you to figure out.

**Original answer below for PHP >= 5.4.0**

**Short answer:**   try `gzdecode()` or `zlib_decode()` instead of `gzuncompress()`.

**Long answer...**

In python (python 3):

```
>>> print(zlib.decompress.__doc__)
decompress(string[, wbits[, bufsize]]) -- Return decompressed string.

Optional arg wbits is the window buffer size.  Optional arg bufsize is
the initial output buffer size.
>>> print(zlib.MAX_WBITS)
15
>>> print(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
31
```

This implies that the data was originally compressed using a window size of 31. In PHP the default window size for most zlib functions is 15, hence `gzuncompress()` and `gzinflate()` fail. However, it seems that `gzdecode()` and `zlib_decode()` do work ( I don't actually know *why*):

**Compress using python3**

```
>>> import zlib
>>> compressor = zlib.compressobj(wbits=(16+zlib.MAX_WBITS))
>>> compressed = compressor.compress(b'Here is a test string compressed by Python with a window size of 31\n')
>>> compressed += compressor.flush()
>>> compressed
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\r\xca\xb1\r\x800\x0c\x04\xc0\x9e)~\x05\xc4\x12\x94\xac\x00\xe4!.\x12#\xdb\x92\x15\xa6\x87\xabo\xa5\x11\xe2\xd8\x11\xf4\x80\x87I\xbfqj{\x8c\xee,8\x06\xb6\x11U;R\xa2\xfe/\xa5\x17M\xb8\xbc\x84^X\xe6\xe9\x03\xabEV\xdbD\x00\x00\x00'
>>> open('/tmp/compressed', 'wb').write(compressed)
85
```

**Decompress using PHP**

```
php > $compressed = file_get_contents('/tmp/compressed');
php > print gzuncompress($compressed);
PHP Warning:  gzuncompress(): data error in php shell code on line 1
php > print gzinflate($compressed);
PHP Warning:  gzinflate(): data error in php shell code on line 1
php > print gzdecode($compressed);
Here is a test string compressed by Python with a window size of 31
php > print zlib_decode($compressed);
Here is a test string compressed by Python with a window size of 31
```

Comment: zlib_decode is very good but added in php 5.4.0 ... my host is php 5.3.38

Comment: @user3747500 : updated answer with compression filter solution.