# Are these Both php - gzdecode functions same?

Tags: php, function, gzip

i faced **PHP: Call to undefined function gzdecode()** error
few days back so i have been using this in php

```
function gzdecode($data) 
{ 
   return gzinflate(substr($data,10,-8)); 
}
```

ref: [PHP: Call to undefined function gzdecode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801908/php-call-to-undefined-function-gzdecode)

i found this old code snippet while looking in old php files , so can i use above code instead of this one ?

```
function gzdecode($data) {
  $g=tempnam('/tmp', 'php-gz');
  @file_put_contents($g, $data);
  ob_start();
  readgzfile($g);
  $d=ob_get_clean();
  unlink($g);
  return $d;
}
```

Comment: Given that `gzinflate`, `gzdecode` and `readgzfile` are all from the Zlib PHP extension, I'd be very surprised if the original didn't work but either replacement did.

Comment: Why can't you use the built-in functions? Are you on an older PHP version? Upgrade. Do you not have ZLib extension installed? Install it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your php.ini, simply enable the `zlib` extension to use `gzencode`. Each compression method has some slight differences.

Please read an abstract of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/621987/382536 by @thomasrutter

All of these are usable. I would use gzencode() because it is self-contained; its output is the same as if you had used the gzip command line tool.

There is not really much difference between the three.

- gzencode() uses the fully self-contained gzip format, same as the
  gzip command line tool
- gzcompress() uses the raw ZLIB format. It is
  similar to gzencode but with less header data, etc. I think it was
  intended for streaming.
- gzdeflate() uses the raw DEFLATE algorithm on
  its own, which is the basis for both the other formats.

Comment: Its already enabled but still getting the error , thats why i had to sue this custom fucntion., thanks